# Kotlin generics and TypeVariable

Tags: generics, kotlin, type-variables

I'd like to type:

```
        project.tasks<JmhTask> {
            ...
        }
```

Instead

```
        project.tasks.withType(JmhTask::class.java) {
            ...
        }
```

`tasks` is of `TaskContainer` type, which extends `interface DomainObjectCollection<T> extends Collection<T>`

`DomainObjectCollection` also defines `::withType` as follows:

`<S extends T> DomainObjectCollection<S> withType(Class<S> type, Action<? super S> configureAction);`

I tried to do the following (first against `TaskContainer` receiver for simplicity):

```
    inline operator fun <reified S> TaskContainer.invoke(configureAction: Action<in S>?) =
            withType(S::class.java, configureAction)
```

Unfortunately `withType` is marked red:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
withType(Class<TypeVariable(S)!>, (Closure<Any!>..Closure<*>))   where S = TypeVariable(S) for    fun <S : Task!> withType(type: Class<S!>, configureClosure: (Closure<Any!>..Closure<*>)): DomainObjectCollection<S!> defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer
withType(Class<TypeVariable(S)!>, Action<in TypeVariable(S)!>)   where S = TypeVariable(S) for    fun <S : Task!> withType(type: Class<S!>, configureAction: Action<in S!>): DomainObjectCollection<S!> defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this

```
inline operator fun <reified S : Task> TaskContainer.invoke(configureAction: Action<in S>) =
    withType(S::class.java, configureAction)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have something with a `DomainObjectCollection<S>` receiver instead?

Comment: I think so. Have you tried to replace `TaskContainer` with `DomainObjectCollection<S>`?